# Are the IMG files in the AVD data directory really encrypted?

Tags: virtualization, avd-manager, android-studio

If I enable phone encryption with password or PIN on my Android Virtual Device, will that actually make the raw NAND images (`*.img` / `*.qcow2`) encrypted?  Does it render the data in those files inaccessible?

If the `*.img` and `*.qcow2` files are really sector-level-encrypted, is there a script or program to decrypt them outside of the AVD?

I'm not referring to the `sdcard` `img` and `qcow2` files, but rather the `userdata-qemu` `img` and `qcow2` files.

Reference:

- https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#data-filedir

Comment: Sector level encryption would be in Android Full Disc Encryption which no longer used for modern devices. Usually now File Based Encryption is used. If it is used in your case you should be able to mount the image but file names and data can be encrypted.

Comment: @Robert, so the belief is that if encryption is enabled in AVD, that the image files will have their data encrypted.  If not by sector, then by file.  But with either case the data at rest is not decryptable without the decryption keys and tokens.

Comment: The Android encryption has been designed to work with a hardware security element as it can be found in ARM CPUs. Such a hardware element is of course missing in the emulator. The main purpose of the emulator is to provide an environment for app development. I would not use it for security critical data.

Comment: @Robert, good point about the missing SE.  But my understanding about the android keystore is that both the PIN and SE are mixed to provide the initial entropy for the encryption.  Even if there is no SE (null SE), if mixed with a sufficiently complex PIN (password really), I would think reasonable security could still be achieved.  For example Oreo allows for 17 char passwords providing ~102 bits of entropy.  102 bits is "pretty good", if my assumptions are not totally off base.

Comment: originally the user password was used via key derivation to encrypt the user data. But on modern devices the architecture is more complex and user password is use for authentication against Android Gatekeeper. If I remember correctly the user password is not used for data encryption anymore. Security of encrypted data mainly depends on the hardware security based keystone...

Comment: @Robert, good points.  A strong passphrase to unlock a trivial keystore does no good.  I just noticed that the AVD `emulator` command allows me to pass `-qemu` commands.  I'll look at converting the image files to `qcow2` encrypted images and see if I can solve this problem that way.  If I get it working I'll report back.

Comment: You may also check the Genymotion emulator (free for private use). It bases on VirtualBox and VirtualBox has the feature to encrypt virtual drives by a  password. I am not sure if disc-encryption can be used with Genymotion but it would be worth a try.